# How to check the latest version of the reporting plugin?

Tags: maven

I'm using the `mvn versions:display-plugin-updates` to check the latest version of my plugins. The result is as the following:-

```
[INFO] 
[WARNING] The following plugins do not have their version specified:
[WARNING]   maven-clean-plugin .......................... (from super-pom) 2.5
[WARNING]   maven-compiler-plugin ........................................ 3.1
[WARNING]   maven-deploy-plugin ......................... (from super-pom) 2.7
[WARNING]   maven-install-plugin ........................ (from super-pom) 2.4
[WARNING]   maven-jar-plugin ............................................. 2.4
[WARNING]   maven-jarsigner-plugin ....................................... 1.2
[WARNING]   maven-resources-plugin ....................................... 2.6
[WARNING]   maven-surefire-plugin ..................................... 2.14.1
[INFO]
```

Regarding to the result above, it seems that the `reporting plugin` has not been checked. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it is a limitation for `version plugin`.

Could you please help to advise further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the issue tracker it seems the plugin should do that: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-83

You may try to execute the plugin using the fully qualified name instead of the partial one (there is a hint on this here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-69)

Comment: Does the `fully qualified name` means `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.0:display-plugin-updates`?